# where are webmatrix logs by default?

Tags: php, windows, iis, logging, webmatrix

I have installed Webmatrix IIS express on my windows 7 machine.
Where can i find the debug logs ?
I am running wordpress if that matters on it with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, they are in your "My Documents" folder in a folder named "IIS Express".   See [IISExpress Log File Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798264/iisexpress-log-file-location) for more information.