# Newly created Asp.net Web App can ONLY RUN ONCE (in VS2017)

Tags: asp.net, dns, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

**Intro:**

When i run an asp.net web app that is freshly created, it runs just fine.
However, it runs only for the 1st time. Subsequent runs will fail with this message:

[image]

The only way to make it run again is to restart VS2017.
Not even restarting IIS/IISExpress will make it work again.

At this point my instincts tell me there is something stupid/silly going on. What on earth is going on here?

**Here is my configuration:**

> - I am using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.8.4
> - .Net Framework Version 4.7.03056
> - Project: Asp.net Web Application (.Net Framework) ==>  MVC
> - This is being run under - IIS Express (Internet Explorer)

**Here are more details about the error im seeing:**

```
The error page simply says "Can't reach this page".
```

When i click on the "More information" expansion link, i see following (mentioned above):

```
There was a temporary DNS error. Try refreshing the page.
Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
```

Now, if i click on the "Fix connection problems" button, the Windows Network Diagnostics window popups up and says:

```
The remove device or resource won't accept this connection
```

If i click on "View detailed information" link at the bottom of this popup, i see following details:

```
The device or resource (localhost) is not set up to accept connections on port 'X' (where X is my localhost dev port).
```

[image]

**Summary:**

In the end, there is no real reason why port 'X' is not working any more. If i change the port number from Visual Studio the web app will run. But as i mentioned before, restarting Visual Studio will allow me to run for the 1st time.

> *** Updated ***
>
> I found a great work-around solution. Instead of running (F5), i
>   simply choose a view (.CSHTML) and execute that view itself
>   (right-click --> View in browser). This seems to work just fine every
>   time without messing up the port.

Comment: FYI - this is starting to get really annoying!

Comment: Does the port still show up as listening on localhost in `netstat -ano` ? Is there any chance this is a IPv4 vs IPv6 issue - do you still get the same error if you try `http://127.0.0.1:11057/` instead? I can only think that you're crashing the web process somehow, and changing the port or restarting VS will restart it, but I can't imagine how that's happening. Is there anything in the system event log or [IIS Express logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5799798/243245) if you have them?

Comment: If i try http://127.0.0.1:11057, i still get the same error.

Comment: if i run the netstat -ano command, i dont see 127.0.0.1:11057 listed.

Comment: Standard questions: Did you try rebooting?  Did you try running Visual Studio as Administrator?